# Episodic Memory from Dynamic Memory Networks

Tags: python, keras

The episodic memory module from [DMN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07285) has a unique state update mechanism that is based on the attention:
[image]

Equation 8 describes the gate `g`, the attention map, is used to compute the next state between a GRU and the previous state. My current implementation uses:

```
class EpisodicMemory(L.Wrapper):
  """Episodic memory from DMN."""
  def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
    self.grucell = L.GRUCell(units, name=kwargs['name']+'_gru') # Internal cell
    super().__init__(self.grucell, **kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    """Build the layer."""
    _, _, ctx_shape = input_shape
    self.grucell.build((ctx_shape[0],) + ctx_shape[2:])
    super().build(input_shape)

  def call(self, inputs):
    """Compute new state episode."""
    init_state, atts, cs = inputs
    # GRU pass over the facts, according to the attention mask.
    while_valid_index = lambda state, index: index < tf.shape(cs)[1]
    retain = 1 - atts
    update_state = (lambda state, index: (atts[:,index,:] * self.grucell.call(cs[:,index,:], [state])[0] + retain[:,index,:] * state))
    # Loop over context
    final_state, _ = tf.while_loop(while_valid_index,
                     (lambda state, index: (update_state(state, index), index+1)),
                     loop_vars = [init_state, 0])
    return final_state

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    """Collapse time dimension."""
    return input_shape[0]
```

and used as:

```
# ...
sim_vec = concat([s_s_c, s_m_c, ctx_state, embedded_sents, repeated_q])
sim_vec = att_dense1(sim_vec) # (?, context_size, dim)
sim_vec = att_dense2(sim_vec) # (?, context_size, 1)
episodic_mem = EpisodicMemory(dim, name='episodic_mem')
state = episodic_mem([state, sim_vec, embedded_sents])
# ...
```

Is there a way to implement this in Keras without binding to Tensorflow functions? Even though we can pass constants to a custom RNN cell, say the attention map, we don't know the current index of the loop inside call function.